# Is "Malenium Polycarbonate" (from blue-blocking sunglasses) real?

Tags: chemistry

There are some sunglasses I bought back in the 1990s containing lenses that were constructed from plastic materials that blocked blue light.  Although claims were made by some vendors that the lenses were made of a material called "Malenium Polycarbonate" along with claims that this material was resistent to damage that most sunglasses couldn't withstand (e.g., striking it with a hammer), when I asked around for more information about this material, every person I asked had never heard of "Malenium."

When I Google for the word "Malenium" or the phrase "Malenium Polycarbonate," I get links to web sites selling sunglasses that block blue light, such as the following which makes the same claim.  (Just for fun I checked Wikipedia, and it also doesn't have any information about the word or phrase I typed into Google.)

The following paragraph is from the second-last paragraph of one of the web sites that Google found for me ( http://www.blublocker.biz/pp_information.html ):

- Unlike many other polarized lenses, which are made of cheap plastic, BluBlocker high-resolution polarized sunglasses contain **Malenium Polycarbonate**.  This is **a powerful resin that makes our lenses so strong you can hit them with a hammer and they won’t shatter.**

Anecdote:  *Although I've never tried striking any of these lenses with a hammer, I do remember a pair getting stepped on and the lenses just getting scratched; only the frame broke.*

Not finding information about this material seems peculiar to me, and I wonder if this might just be a different name for some other form of durable plastic.  So, **is Malenium Polycarbonate a real material?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears Malenium is just a trademarked name based on the information [provided here](http://174.36.140.236/malenium-74470956.html) by the Blublocker corporation.

A search for "Malenium Polycarbonate" on Google only provides around 29 results, some are garbage the rest just relate to the Blublocker corporation so there aren't other brands of sunglasses that are made from "Malenium Polycarbonate".

Polycarbonate is just a synthetic resin.

According to [this website](http://www.cdreamin.com/sunglasses.php):

> **Scratch-Resistant Coatings**
>
> Scratch-resistant coatings prolong the life of a pair of sunglasses.
>   Many polycarbonate lenses have this coating to increase their level of
>   scratch resistance to that of CR-39.

So the answer is Malenium is just a trademark and the superior strength is just a marketing claim, as there haven't been any studies comparing "Malenium Polycarbonate" to other sunglasses brands (based on Google search revealing only 29 results) unless one was published offline.